# Using Pod dependencies in custom cocoapod framework getting "use of undeclared type"

Tags: swift, cocoapods, rollbar

I've added Rollbar as a dependency to my cocoapod. In my podspec I have:

```
s.dependency 'Rollbar'
```

Building and running the app that includes my cocoapod as a dependency works fine, but if I open my framework project Xcode complains because it doesn't have the Rollbar dependency imported.

This causes an "Use of unresolved identifier 'Rollbar'" error on the following line:

```
Rollbar.initWithAccessToken("XXX")
```

I understand exactly what is happening, my framework project does not have any idea of the Rollbar dependency, so it doesn't load these classes in. But this affects how I test my framework as it won't compile if I keep it this way.

I'll also note that in my bridging header, I've wrapped the necessary Rollbar `#import` with a `__has_include` to allow bridging header to compile.

```
#if __has_include("Rollbar/Rollbar.h")
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <Rollbar/Rollbar.h>
#endif
```

It doesn't seem possible to do something similar in my Swift file as I get this error:

```
RollbarSetup.swift:2:5: Unexpected platform condition (expected 'os', 'arch', or 'swift')
```

Which leads me to believe this type of conditional is not allowed. I was hoping I could create some mock objects in the framework if the Rollbar dependency wasn't present.

---

Has anyone else encountered this when writing a cocoapod that uses a separate cocoapod dependency? I feel that this is something anyone in this scenario would encounter.

Is there something I can do to allow my framework project to compile?

Answer (score 1):

I have a cocoapod SDK into Swift and I did it with following steps

1. first add Rollbar into `podspec` file
   `s.dependency 'Rollbar', '1.8.1'`
2. Add `import Rollbar` in the View Controller from where you have to set the error message
3. Run the `pod install` command on your example project which is created for your SDK.
4. You are ready to use the Rollbar now.
5. RollBar SDK initialization

```
let configuration = RollbarConfiguration()
configuration.crashLevel = "critical"
configuration.environment = "production"
Rollbar.initWithAccessToken("POST_CLIENT_ITEM_ACCESS_TOKEN", configuration: configuration)
Rollbar.error("Error Message")
```

You are done with Rollbar integration.

Answer (score 0):

The Podspec file should be wrote by the author of the pod, to add a pod to your project you need to add `pod 'Rollbar'` in your Podfile. Also, `#if __has_include` only executes when the file has been already imported, so importing it in this statement does anything. Since you are using Swift, a simple `import Rollbar` should do the trick, no need for a bridging header.

Comment: I am the author of my pod. Lets call this pod 'Framework-X', it has a dependency of the 'Rollbar' cocoapod and defines this relationship in its podspec. When I add 'Framwork-X' to an app project using a Podfile, the Rollbar transitive dependency installs correctly and the app runs. My problem is that when I'm developing 'Framework-X', outside of the app project environment, my framework won't compile because it doesn't include the Rollbar dependency. This doesn't hinder my development too much but it makes testing a pain as I can't include certain files to this target.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were trying to implement the Pod in your app. Have you tried the steps [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html)?

Comment: Yea I think so, thats how I set rollbar as a dependency in my podspec. `spec.dependency 'Rollbar'`

Comment: You said in your question `s.dependency`, so I thought you wrote `s` instead of `spec`.

Comment: I'm wondering if I just can't develop my framework anymore without the context of the cocoapod workspace as the standalone project doesn't have the cocoapod dependencies.